# Is it possible to set width of one part in pixel and width of remaining part in percentage without lost it's responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fixed

```css
aside {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 220;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

article {
    background-color: red;
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
        <aside>
            <ul>
                <li><a>1st item</a></li>
                <li><a>2nd item</a></li>
                <li><a>3rd item</a></li>
                <li><a>4th item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
            
        <article>
          <p>contents here</p>
        </article>
```

In the above code i'm tried to create a menu part and content part.the
speciality of the menu part is it's width remain same even if window is resized. But the content part need to be resized according to window resizing.but here the design given above is not a responsive design.is it possible to design such a  menu and content part without lost it's responsiveness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width` and `float` properties from `article` and add `overflow: hidden`

```css
aside {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  float:left;
}

aside ul {
  list-style: none;
}

article {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a>1st item</a></li>
    <li><a>2nd item</a></li>
    <li><a>3rd item</a></li>
    <li><a>4th item</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
            
<article>
  <p>contents here</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use css3 calc(), this seems like a direct use case.

```css
aside {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px; // modified, you did not indicate units
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
}

article {
  background-color: red;
  width:calc(100% - 100px); // modified
  height:100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a>1st item</a></li>
    <li><a>2nd item</a></li>
    <li><a>3rd item</a></li>
    <li><a>4th item</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>

<article>
  <p>contents here</p>
</article>
```

Read about browser support here: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
aside {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 220;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}

article {
    background-color: red;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  
  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li><a>1st item</a></li>
      <li><a>2nd item</a></li>
      <li><a>3rd item</a></li>
      <li><a>4th item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>

  <article>
    <p>contents here</p>
  </article>

</div>
```